# Access VBA Putting name of a Field as a Record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am with a little bit of a coding problem that I don't know how to solve. I want to put in the table as a record a field name of another table in the same Database.

I will give you an example:

Table1 
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGTUA.png)

Table 2
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfWGX.png)

The table 1 is update weekly from an external source so I need to record the field name as a record in the second table using VBA language. Does anybody knows if it's possible?

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
Dim db As Database
Dim fld As Field
Dim sql As String
Set db = CurrentDb

For Each fld In db.TableDefs("YourTable").Fields

    sql = "Insert into YourSummaryTable([Date], Hours) select '" & fld.Name & "', sum([" & fld.Name & "]) as s from YourTable"
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql


Next fld
```

Note that you've used a reserved word `Date` as a fieldname, which isn't best practice and requires the use of the square brackets in the query.

Comment: Hey thks you're code works very well. However when I run it, appears a window with "Enter Parameter Value" for each name of the field. Is there a way I do not need to enter nothing by end and the record stays with the name of the field?

Comment: What data type is your `Date` field ?

Comment: It can be whatever I want. But I would prefer Date\Time or Short Text

Comment: The above sample was based on a text field. If you want dates you will likely have to replace the `'` with `#` for Access. The code sample I gave worked without Enter Parameter Value error for me, so either you have not copied the code correctly or there's something different in your schema that I didn't have.